# Spring MVCException handling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a MVC controller having at least 50 functions in there and my call to the services are not wrapped around try catch and some of the exceptions are getting eaten. I am trying to find the best way to handle this.

Shall I wrap the calls around try catch in individual function or is there any function I can use that can log the exception. I dont want to send alternate view or something just simply want to record in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at `@ExceptionHandler` (controller-based exception Handling) or `@ControllerAdvice` (global exception handling). [This article](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc) explains both in detail.

The other possible solution is [AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-api).

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `SimpleMappingExceptionResolver` and override `logException()` like this:

```
public class CustomExceptionResolver extends SimpleMappingExceptionResolver {
    @Override
    protected void logException(Exception ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        if (ex != null) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the exception occurs in the view, the above will not log it.  For this, you can extend `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
public class ViewExceptionLoggerInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        if (ex != null) {
            logger.error(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did add that but it didn't do anything. Do I have to include something else too?

Comment: Did you configure the beans in your Spring config?

Comment: Nope. how can I do that?

Comment: See https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-exception-handling-example/ and https://mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/ for the xml configuration. I'm sure there is some newer annotation way to set it up, but I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Also see https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc (it's been updated since 2013)

Answer (score 0):

To centralize exception handling, use the follow:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandler{

   @ExceptionHandler(SomeException.class)
   public final ResponseEntity<ReturnValue> handleSomeException(SomeException ex) {
    // exception handling
   }
}
```

If you need `ModelAndView` as a return value, just change the return type to it, and build the proper object in the body.